# Can't change button text color in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, button, textcolor

I tried just setting `android:textColor="#FFFFFF"` and this didn't work so I checked other answers to the problem to find solutions.

I tried making a selector and then setting the android:textColor attribute to this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

That didn't work either.

I tried setting the text color programmatically:
      `verifyButton.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));`

That didn't work either. The button text color is a dark grey and I can't seem to change it to white.

Comment: `setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));` ??????????

Comment: it should be `getApplicationContext` instead of `getApplication`

Comment: I think the link below can help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176365/how-do-i-change-the-text-color-of-a-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176365/how-do-i-change-the-text-color-of-a-button)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

### FYI

Why calling  **getApplication()** ?

> getApplication() is only available on the Activity class and in the
>   Service class, whereas getApplicationContext() is declared in the
>   Context class.

- You should call `getApplicationContext()` instead of
  `getApplication()` .

  **setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));**

You should call **getApplicationContext()** or **Direct Activity Class** .

> Return the context of the single, global Application object of the
>   current process.

[getApplication() vs. getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext)

Comment: My mistake. However, I tried both suggestions and neither worked. The text is still dark grey.

Comment: check your theme please .

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: @Questioner have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860906/widget-appcompat-button-colorbuttonnormal-shows-gray

Comment: I made a separate theme with white text colour and assigned it to the button like in the link you posted. The text is still not white.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also encountered this problem. I found that I set hint="AAA" for Button and then set textColor. This is invalid, it only works for text. I should set textColorHint to help those who have experienced this minor problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use getApplication(). Use getContext() instead. Or use ContextCompat.getColor() for backward compatibility