# btn.setEnabled(false); does not make the button text grayed out in targetSdkVersion 25

Tags: android, android-studio, button

After updating Android Studio to 2.3 and gradle version 3.3,

> btn.setEnabled(false);

Text color on the disabled button does not gray out. Functionality is working fine but I have an issue with the text color which can be misunderstood by users. 
btn.setTextColor() is an option but then it can be tedious. Any other alternatives would be helpful..

Comment: Do you applied any styles to button?

Comment: No. Button has an image background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- disabled state -->
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#9D9FA2" /> 
  <item android:color="#000"/>
</selector>
```

From: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225166/android-textcolor-of-disabled-button-in-selector-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (btn.isEnabled() == true)
{
btn.setTextColor(int Color);
}
else
{
btn.setTextColor(int Color);
}
```

It will definitely work. You can define colors respectively.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

from java end:

```
    button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.red)); 

or 

    button.setTextColor(0xff0000); //SET YOUR COLOR 
or

    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

and in xml :

```xml
<Button android:id="@+id/mybtn" 
        android:text="text textx "  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />  <-- SET TEXT COLOR HERE -->
```

Ref.: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176365/how-do-i-change-the-text-color-of-a-button)